# How to work with refs and useEffect it React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to run some code when the `ref.current` is available, but if I log the value inside the useEffect it's only get triggered once with the value of null.

How can I wait/run some code when `ref.current` have a value?

```
function Feed() {
  const [items, setItem] = useState<IItem[]>([])

  const lastEl = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  useEffect(() => {

    console.log('here', lastEl);
       const lastFeedEl = lastEl?.current

const feedObserver = new IntersectionObserver(handleLastItemDisplay)

if(lastFeedEl) feedObserver.observe(lastFeedEl)
  }, [lastEl.current])




  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const items = await fetchItems()
      setItems(items)
    })()
  }, [])


  return (
    <div>
      {items.slice(0, 4).map((item, idx) => {
        if (idx === 2) return <div key={item.id} ref={lastEl}> <Item  item={item} /> </div>
        return <Item key={item.id} item={item} />
      }
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Feed;
```

Comment: What is is your wanting to do with the ref when you have it?.

Comment: set an observer on the item with the ref(implement infinte scroll in general, observing the last element)

Comment: Ok, in that case what I would do is pass a prop to your `Item` component, and the `useEffect` inside the Item component will then get you your ref.  If altering Item is not an option, wrap the Item component inside another component .

Comment: I'm wrapping the Item compnent with a div

Comment: No wrap inside another component..   The `useEffect` will then on mount have the correct ref, at the correct time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that the DIV doesn't get rendered until setState is called, your `useEffect` is then getting called too early and not when the DIV gets mounted.

A simple solution to this is just wrap the DIV inside another component, this component will then have it's own `useEffect` that will get called at the correct time.

Another bonus is the code just become easier to manage too,.

Never be afraid to split React component's up, they become much easier to reason with & debug.  There are also nice performance benefits to doing this too.

```
function ItemOB({children}:{children: React.ReactNode}) {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(ref.current); //this should be the DIV
    }, [])
    return <div ref={ref}>{children}</div>
}

function Feed() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<IItem[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const items = await fetchItems()
      setItems(items)
    })()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {items.slice(0, 4).map((item, idx) => {
        if (idx === 2) return <ItemOB key={item.id}> <Item  item={item} /> </ItemOB>
        return <Item key={item.id} item={item} />
      }
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Feed;
```